# LINQ group by sequence and count with sorting

Tags: c#, linq, count, linq-group

I am searching a best performance method to group and count sequences with sorting using LINQ. I will be processing files even bigger than 500 MBs so performance is most important key in that task.

```
List<int[]> num2 = new List<int[]>();
num2.Add(new int[] { 35, 44 });
num2.Add(new int[] { 200, 22 });
num2.Add(new int[] { 35, 33 });
num2.Add(new int[] { 35, 44 });
num2.Add(new int[] { 3967, 11 });
num2.Add(new int[] { 200, 22 });
num2.Add(new int[] { 200, 2 });
```

The result have to be like this:

```
[35,   44]  => 2
[200,  22] => 2
[35,   33] => 1
[35,   44] => 1
[3967, 11] => 1
[200,  2 ] => 1
```

I have done something like this:

```
        Dictionary<int[], int> result2 = (from i in num2
                                       group i by i into g
                                       orderby g.Count() descending
                                       select new { Key = g.Key, Freq = g.Count() })
                          .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Freq);

        SetRichTextBox("\n\n Second grouping\n");

        foreach (var i in result2)
        {
            SetRichTextBox("\nKey: ");
            foreach (var r in i.Key)
            {
                SetRichTextBox(r.ToString() + "  ");
            }

            SetRichTextBox("\n  Value: " + i.Value.ToString());

        }
```

But it is not working properly. Any help?

Comment: What isn't working? What error are you getting?

Comment: `to group and count sequences` what group? what count? your example doesn't show any thing meaningful for what you said, poorly explained question

Comment: Are the arrays always of length 2?

Comment: Each int array should be printed once and showed how many times it occured in the list. Each array have tha same size but not always 2.

Comment: Why do you use List<int[]> and how do you get it? If you build it yourself during file reading, then directly use Dictionary<int[], int>. Such approach will save you from groupby step. You will need to sort dictionary by values.

Comment: Shad I will check your idea.

Comment: You'll need to define a hashcode for your key, which may be a way to go.  There isn't a default one for int[] because its expensive, but you can use a custom type of your own that implements its own hashcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arrays of length 2, this will work.

```
num2.GroupBy(a => a[0])
    .Select(g => new { A0 = g.Key, A1 = g.GroupBy(a => a[1]) })
    .SelectMany(a => a.A1.Select(a1 => new { Pair = new int[] { a.A0, a1.Key }, Count = a1.Count() }));
```

I think that should give you optimal performance; you could also try an `.AsParallel()` clause after your first Select statement.

This strategy (grouping successively by the n-th element of the arrays) generalises to arrays of arbitrary length:

```
var dim = 2;

var tuples = num2.GroupBy(a => a[0])
    .Select(g => new Tuple<int[], List<int[]>>(new [] { g.Count(), g.Key }, g.Select(a => a.Skip(1).ToArray()).ToList()));

for (int n = 1; n < dim; n++)
{
    tuples = tuples.SelectMany(t => t.Item2.GroupBy(list => list[0])
        .Select(g => new Tuple<int[], List<int[]>>(new[] { g.Count() }.Concat(t.Item1.Skip(1)).Concat(new [] { g.Key }).ToArray(), g.Select(a => a.Skip(1).ToArray()).ToList())));
}

var output = tuples.Select(t => new { Arr = string.Join(",", t.Item1.Skip(1)), Count = t.Item1[0] })
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Count)
    .ToList();
```

which generates an output of

```
Arr = "35, 44", Count = 2
Arr = "200, 22", Count = 2
Arr = "35, 33", Count = 1
Arr = "200, 2", Count = 1
Arr = "3967, 11", Count = 1
```

in your example.  I'll let you test it for higher dimensions. :)

You should be able to parallelise these queries without too much difficulties, as the successive groupings are independent.

Comment: Hi, how about variable int arrays?

Comment: OK, there should be a way to do that.  If your array size is n >= 1, you can perform an elegant Aggregate operation.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Done.  OK, it was more than a few minutes.  You could quite easily make an Aggregate out of this, but I don't think we need to make it any more complicated than it already is.

Comment: Its performance isn't bad, but it could be better.  For better performance, you need to find a good hashing algorithm for an array of its.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var results = from x in nums
              group x by new { a = x[0], b = x[1] } into g
              orderby g.Count() descending
              select new
              {
                  Key = g.Key,
                  Count = g.Count()
              };

foreach (var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0},{1}]=>{2}", result.Key.a, result.Key.b, result.Count));
```

The trick is to come up with a way to compare the values in the array, instead of the arrays themselves.

The alternative (and possibly better option) would be to transform your data from `int[]` to some custom type, override the equality operator on that custom type, then just `group x by x into g`, but if you're really stuck with `int[]` then this works.

Comment: The problem is, this doesn't generalise to arrays of arbitrary length, as OP requested in his comments.

Comment: @RobLyndon: That's why I provided the alternative solution, one which is far more robust. The "the data is always a `List<int[]>` of equal length `int[]`" has a bad smell, and this problem becomes trivial once you throw them into any custom format whatsoever.